# OpenSCManager on local machine - NULL vs "localhost" as lpMachineName

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-services

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagera) on `lpMachineName` param of `OpenSCManager` *WinApi* function:

> If the pointer is NULL or points to an empty string, the function
> connects to the service control manager on the local computer.

Is passing "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" will result the exact same behavior as passing NULL or an empty string? Or should I perform a check in my logic and substitute "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" with NULL, before calling `OpenSCManager`?

Comment: It sounds like it. However, I wonder if it is listening on another local IP address aside from `127.0.0.1` ... there could be anything in `127.0.0.0/8` range.

Comment: result will be much more worse from performance view. in several time. need use 0 if you need connect to local database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***OpenSCManager*** of course uses a special, fast path, to connect to the local service control manager. for use this fast path ***OpenSCManager*** need somehow detect that we want connect to local database. this of course done by check ***lpMachineName***. the best and documented variant - will be use ***NULL*** pointer here. then almost same effect will be if use empty string. then possible ***OpenSCManager*** can compare ***lpMachineName*** with some hard-coded strings. in my test, it compare ***lpMachineName*** with ***localhost*** and ***.*** and if not match - need go to slow path. for ***127.0.0.1*** string function not check.

for compare fast and slow path, some internal fragments of ***OpenSCManager*** :

fast path: (here and selected path)

[image]

slow path:

[image]

fast path:

[image]

slow path:

[image]

fast path:

[image]

slow path:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Could you please elaborate more regarding the 3 pairs of stacks attached? What are the params of each slow-fast "pair"? Thanks!

Comment: @golosovsky - "fast" dump with 0 in *lpMachineName* and "slow" with "127.0.0.1". this is simply show different - much better use 0 instead "127.0.0.1"